# Нужно ли выделять запятыми "кроме шахмат"?

Tags: запятые

Старика кроме шахмат ничего не интересовало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

***Старика, кроме шахмат, ничего не интересовало.***

См. **ПАС**:

> **§ 78…** Примечание 1. Оборот с предлогом *кроме* имеет два значения: а) одно совпадает со значением слов *за исключением*, т. е. имеет значение исключения из ряда подобных предметов: *На всех берегах залива на протяжении сотен верст мною не было встречено ни одного человека, и, **кроме горчайшей полыни и сухого бурьяна**, я не сорвал ни одной травинки* (Пауст.); *Вершинин отправил луговиков в институт, всех, **кроме Свиридовой**, — ее он включил в высокогорный отряд* (Зал.); б) другое — это обозначение включения в ряд подобных предметов: *У Бунина, **кроме блестящих, совершенно классических рассказов**, есть необычайные по чистоте рисунки* (Пауст.); *Я слышал, **кроме гудения мотора**, еще несколько звуков* (Пауст.).
>
> **В настоящее время различия в значениях оборотов со словом *кроме* не сказываются на пунктуации: и в том и в другом случае предусмотрено выделение запятыми**. Однако в прошлом обороты со значением включения знаками препинания не выделялись. Ср.: ***Кроме учителей** на собрание пришли и ученики. — **Кроме учителей**, на собрание никто не пришел*.

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=318#pp318

Answer (score 1):

1. Обособление оборота со значением исключения **регламентируется** правилами.

**[Справочник по пунктуации](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/krome-kogo-chego)**

```
Обороты с предлогом «кроме» ОБЫЧНО обособляются, 
если предлог можно заменить словами «исключая, не 
считая кого-либо, чего-либо».Запятые МОГУТ не 
ставиться, если предлог «кроме» имеет значение 
«дополнительно, вдобавок к чему-либо».  Однако и при 
таком значении предлога постановка запятых ВОЗМОЖНА.
```

Но если судить **по практике** письма, то оно скорее **факультативно**, **[например:](https://rsport.ria.ru/20230922/alisa_gallyamova-1897901070.html)**

*Ему сильно повезло. Звезды так сошлись. В нашей семье я была женой и матерью, а он просто шахматистом. Было сложно, потому что он в быту был никакой. **Его кроме шахмат ничего не интересовало.** То есть мне надо было самой делать буквально все.*

2. Многое зависит от **контекста и от структуры** предложения, сравнить:

(1) *Старика, / **кроме шахмат**, // ничего не интересовало.*

(2) ***Кроме шахмат** старика // ничего не интересовало.*